# MVC3 Get last 3 records in Model using Entity Framework

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, for-loop

I'm a MVC Noob and I need some help cleaning up my code.

I have a index view (Razor and VB.NET) that is supposed to return the last 3 items in my model. This is what I did. It works, but It looks ugly and I'm sure there is a better way of doing it. Please help.

My View

```
   For i As Integer = (Model.Count.ToString() - 3) To (Model.Count.ToString() - 1)
       Dim currentItem = Model(i)

        @<tr>
         <td>...do some stuff with my currentItem</td>
        </tr>
   Next
```

Comment: Will there always be at least 3 items?  If it's possible there are less, you will throw exceptions.

Comment: True, there could be less...in which case I added this above that statement: @If Model.Count.ToString() >= 3 Then ..... Else For each item in model next....End if

Comment: @ModelType IEnumerable(Of ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Model is an Enumerable of something, then you can use Linq extension methods to do something like this (in C#, I don't do VB)

```
foreach(var m in Model.Reverse().Take(3))
{
    // your code
}
```

If you need them in the original order, you can always Reverse() again afterwards.

Although, if you aren't going to use the rest of the elements, then you should actually do this in your controller, or business layer and only return the three elements.

Comment: I like this, lot easier than doing a Skip then Take.

Comment: That's MUCH better thanks! Unfortunately I still need all the elements for something else. For interest sake, in VB.Net its

@If Model.Count.ToString() >= 3 Then
   For Each item In Model.Reverse().Take(3)
      Dim currentItem = item

   Next
Else
   ...
End if